# com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException

Tags: java, jersey, pom.xml

Hi I am getting below exception in my web service REST.
I understand that MappableContainerException is just a wrapper exception that Jersey uses if the underlying code threw something that is not mappable to a response (in my case it is the NoClassDefFoundError). But I don't khow how to fix it.

```
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
GRAVE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/rest/util/Model
```

The Model class exist in an other maven project "REST-Util" and I integrated it my pom.xml tlike this :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.rest.util</groupId>
        <artifactId>REST-Util</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I would greatly appreciate it if you can help me solve this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: the scope is not provided, but compile or runtime as appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I tried your answer but it didn't work I got the same error

Comment: can you check if the final archive (WAR or EAR) has the REST-Util-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT dependency inside it?

Comment: Yes the final archive JAR has REST-Util insise it

Comment: Cool. does it have the class Jersey reports to be missing in the correct folder structure? e.g. the Model class should be available in the `com/rest/util` folder structure relative to root.

Comment: Yes I did check that the Model class is available in the com.rest.util package

Comment: is this package (`com/rest/util`) in the root of the final Jar?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean very well, the project REST-Util which has the package com.rest.util is inside the MavenDependencies of the final Jar, it can't be in the root of the final Jar can it?

Comment: OK, I think that's where the issue is. The final Jar that you generate should have this class in the package relative to the root of the Jar per se. If you have the REST-util jar as is (be it in root or MavenDependencies directory you mentioned above), it's not going to help.

Answer (score 1):

Put your required JAR inside `WebContent\WEB-INF\lib` folder.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely answer is that a dependency contract has changed or is different from what you are expecting(perhaps a version issue).  Likely an interface method named changed, but it's not limited to that, it could also be a class name change or some other interface facet too.

I ran into this same error when renaming a method of a library I wrote where it seemed that the cached version differed from the file version and Jersey failed to pick up the name change and kept referring to the old name.  I cleaned the project and everything was good after that.

ALSO, make sure that you are exporting your dependency in the Java build path.  That's likely cause of the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/rest/util/Model` error