# com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException when debugging Tomcat

Tags: java, rest, tomcat

When I host my project using `startup` command in `bin` folder of Tomcat, it is running well, but when I debug it using tomcat (`catalina jpda start`) and when I send a rest call there is an error in the tomcat console:

```
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException unable to intialise the class
```

The following error is shown in console:

```
Mar 04, 2016 6:02:13 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.org.j2ee.flightmanager.abacus.AbacusWrapper.<clinit>(AbacusWrapper.java:46)
```

Comment: Is this similar post helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16968675/466738 ?

Comment: no i don't think it is similar to that in my case i am able run the project by using startup in bin folder but when i try to debug using the command "catalina jpda start" from command line and try to call a rest api it showing the above error.Container failed to intialise a class.